# Access error 3188 using OLE object fields for storing .jpg images

Tags: locking, ms-access-2010, blob, image-store

Using 2 OLE object fields for front and side face pics, I get an error 3188 (locking caused by another session in same machine) only for the 2nd field, even procedures are the same as OLE object field or a string indicator are passed as parameters.

HI, all!

First of all I want to apologize for my written English since it’s not my native language, as I am a Buenos Aires (Argentine) based software developer.

I’m facing a very strange issue with a HR application running in Access 2010 using an .mdb format database on machines with Win 7 & Win 10 both x86 and x64 OS. Due to corporate policies and interactions with other applications I have the following constraints:

1)  Can’t change the DB type, must keep .mdb and unable to switch to .accdb.

2)  Can’t use attached files.

3)  Main table is People and has two OLE object fields for front and side 
face pics and neither can split in two tables nor build another DB for neither photo storing nor just store references to external files.

What is the problem? The DB has 12 K records, where 4.5 K has pictures and it’s reaching the 2 Gb limit size. Nowadays it has 1.85 Gb, where pics occupy 1.2 Gb and data & all the other stuff 0.65 Gb. I’m trying to reduce the 1.2 Gb pics’ size to 0.25 Gb so as to be able to store pics for the rest 7.5 K records, reaching a DB of 1.4 GB.

As it’s well known Access stores .jpg files in .bmp format within OLE fields increasing enormously the amount of space used for each pic. Photos have 180x240 pixels, a 10-15K .jpg file vs. a 130K .bmp each.

Those pic files are edited in two forms, displayed in many other and printed in several reports.

The main idea for solving the problem? Use get/append chunk for retrieving/storing photos in compressed .jpg format. In that thought, I passed thru many BLOB (binary large object) field conversions and import/export file handling, but I found none suitable for my job:

- 2 BLOB excerpts from MSDN
- Stephen Leban’s export OLE to JPG
- Invantive Query Tool
- Db-Pix 3.0
- MSPaint.exe calling (https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=392408)

The only one that seemed to serve for my purposes was this last one, so I’ve ended writing four functions:

- OLEbmp_FILjpg: export original OLE field in .bmp format to .jpg file (programmatically controlling MSPAINT.exe)
- FILjpg_OLEjpg: store .jpg file into OLE field In .jpg format
- OLEjpg_FILjpg: export new OLE filed in .jpg format to .jpg file
- FILjpg_CTLimg: fills an image control with a .jpg file

Changes made to the app are:

1)  The initial conversion process works like this:

a.    OLEbmp_FILjpg exports old embedded .bmp to external .jpg file

b.    FILjpg_OLEjpg stores exported .jpg file into new OLE object field

2)  Forms that display pics works as this:

a.    Dependent object frames are replaced by image controls.

b.    On current event:

```
i.  OLEjpg_FILjpg exports OLE embedded field to .jpg file.

ii. FILjpg_CTLimg fills the image control with .jpg file.
```

3)  Reports that display pics works as this:

a.    Dependent object frames are replaced by image controls.

b.    On report activate event (since current event isn’t triggered due to Access bug):

```
i.  OLEjpg_FILjpg exports OLE embedded field to .jpg file.

ii. FILjpg_CTLimg fills the image control with .jpg file.
```

4)  Forms with editable pics works as this:

a.    Dependent object frames are replaced by image controls.

b.    Two command buttons are added for “Modify Pic” and “Delete Pic”.

c.    On current event:

```
i.  OLEjpg_FILjpg exports OLE embedded field to .jpg file.

ii. FILjpg_CTLimg fills the image control with .jpg file.
```

d.    Procedure under Modify Pic button does:

```
i.  New pic is selected from File open dialog.

ii. FILjpg_OLEjpg stores .jpg data in OLE object field.

iii.    FILjpg_CTLimg displays new pic in form.
```

e.    Procedure under Delete Pic does:

```
i.  OLE object field value is set to null.

ii. Image control picture is cleared.
```

Everything works fine, except 4) d) and e), but ONLY FOR THE 2ND OLE OBJECT FIELD.

The described procedures call are repeated twice everywhere, once for front picture and again for side face picture, both together, side face picture code immediately following front face picture code.
As I wrote, it works fine both modification and deletion for front face but always crashes for side face picture, raising “Error 3188 - Could not update; currently locked by another session on this machine.”, even tested standalone and with no other form/query/report open or running on the DB.

I’ve tried this workarounds:

1)  Removed controls and code for front pic and still crashes for side face pic.

2)  Removed controls and code for side face pic and now crashes but for front pic.

3)  Kept both controls and inverted them in the table definition (side face before front pic field) and crashes for 2nd field, now front pic.

The lock seems to happen on the last OLE object either defined in the table (too weird in my opinion) or used or referenced in the code (I’d bet on this), but I checked manually every object instantiation and they’re all ended properly. Indeed, procedures used for working on front and side face pics are the same, handled by passing either OLE object field or a string indicator as a parameter. So why it works with front and not for side face?

Just in case error handling with return code is implemented in every procedure and code created objects (databases, recordsets, file system objects, controls, fields, and so on) are closed and destroyed (set to Nothing) before exiting.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about that "only 2nd -or last- OLE object control is affected by this lock", I gave a try to a crazy idea and it works smoothly at almost no space cost!

I added a 3rd OLE object field to the People table, named Zdummy, filled it with a single char, and wherever in the code there were snippets that operate on front pic OLE object followed by the same for side face pic OLE object, I added immediately after the same stuff for the new dummy OLE object. Somehow it freed the side face field -who knows how!- and I bet on this: a new lock takes place -who knows which!- on the new dummy field, that's not used anywhere except for letting Access play on us.

So if in the near future someone happens to bring light over this obscure behavior, I'd be very happy. Otherwise I'll be sticking to this workaround.

Just in case anyone faces similar problems for handling images on OLE object fields, please post a comment and I'll upload the code for the 4 main functions referred in my first post.

Thanks to all who dedicated a few of their time reading this.

Best regards,
Patrick